# Which utensil or device can be used to make spirals or conveyor screws with vegetables?

Tags: equipment, vegetables, utensils, cutting

I don't know if there exist some tool or utensil to make these spirals or screws.

I mean the shape which I am intending to replicate follows the idea seen in the figure from below:

[image: example of the shape]

Another example of this shape can be seen in [this site](https://kenki-corporation.com/products/screws/)

In other words what I intend to do is to make this sort of accordion or screw sonveyor shapes with cucumbers or perhaps potatoes, and yes without that metal rod in the middle connecting the spirals.

But I don't know if there exist some tool for that? Does anyone how a way how to make this? Please don't say to replicate this using a regular knife because that's now the way how I intend to do this, and kind of it looks difficult. Can someone help me here please? I browsed for different tools on Amazon, but none of those seem to display exactly the result which I am trying to get. So any cooking expert can help me?

Comment: To be absolutely clear, in the final object do you want the "central spar" AS WELL ?  Or was that just for example?

Comment: these devices are really popular for apples in france BTW, folks bring them home as a souvenir!

Answer (score 23):

My favorite tool is a spiral cutter sold for apples or potatoes, here’s an example.

[image]
([Source](https://www.amazon.de/CORVUS-600158-Chipsmaschine-Verschiedene-Spielwaren/))

A tiny screw-plus-rotating-knife gadget is often used for Bavarian radish spirals, e.g.:

[image]
([Source](https://www.amazon.de/Westmark-Rettichschneider-Spiralschneider-langem-Zentrierstab/))

Note that both types will produce spirals without waste, so to achieve the look in your question, you have to gently pull the cut vegetable lengthwise. Depending on the vegetable, the spiral will be more or less inclined to spring back.

For potatoes, frying the stretched spiral will set them, that‘s a common fair food in some places, sometimes going by the name “[Tornado Potatoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado_potato)”

Comment: I thought "Tornado Potatoes" were just going to be curly fries, but they are 100x more awesome.

Answer (score 5):

There are tools [specifically designed to do this with pineapple](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Prokitchen-Pineapple-Spiral-Stainless-Remover/dp/B07BRRKZLD). You could use them on other foods or a large enough diameter, and not too hard. You'd need to hold the turns open a bit to make it look like a screw thread, and the core is also removed

Despite the name, [spiralisers](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OXO-Good-Grips-Hand-Spiralizer/dp/B013KAW5IQ) don't produce tidy spirals very often or easily, but something more like noodles.

Answer (score 4):

It's called a **spiralizer**

They come in many shapes & sizes - this [BBC Good Food guide](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/review/test-best-spiralizers) has a selection

[image]